# Spring framework ERROR 10904

Tags: java, windows, spring, maven

I was trying to build an application using the Spring framework but I got the following errors and am not sure why.
Whenever I try to run the application I get the bellow errors. I did set up my Maven in C drive and my application in D drive due to space. Can that be an issue?

What is causing the errors and how should I go about them?

**ERROR 10904** --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

**ERROR 10904** --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

**ERROR 10904** --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

**INFO 10904** --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/D:/GITHUB/webappaws/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/codeLearner/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/codeLearner/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/codeLearner/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/codeLearner/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/codeLearner/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/codeLearner/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/codeLearner/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, ...

Comment: What do you see when you open http://localhost:8080 in a browser?

Comment: There should be an exception message and stack trace in your log. We need to see that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

What I did when launching the application was instead of relaunching it, I ran it and that's what cause the problem (I think)

When I go open localhost:8080 it displays what it should.

I am learning, which does counts for stupid mistakes and I learn with every new feedback .. not sure why I was voted down though...

Thank you Luke and Jim!